# How to work with proguard rule ? for library .. even i added library provided rule still app crash ...how to resolve it?

Tags: android, proguard

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lpl/droidsonroids/gif/GifInfoHandle;.<init>(JIII)V"
        at pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifInfoHandle.openFd(Native Method)
        at pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifInfoHandle.a(:88)
        at pl.droidsonroids.gif.h.<init>(:170)
        at pl.droidsonroids.gif.h.<init>(:108)
        at com.homeone.deft.android.activity.MainActivity.a(:39)
        at com.homeone.deft.android.e.g.onCreate(:93)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6705)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2768)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1481)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6153)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:758)
```

**I am trying to add proguard rules for my project i got following error .. i do not understand how to resolve it ...it occurred for library method**

Comment: Post your proguard rules file

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this [proguard-rules.pro](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable/blob/dev/sample/proguard-rules.pro) for the library.

```
-keep class pl.droidsonroids.gif.sample.GifSelectorDrawable { *; }

-keepattributes Signature, LineNumberTable

#leakcanary
-keep class org.eclipse.mat.** { *; } 
-dontwarn com.squareup.haha.guava.** 
-dontwarn com.squareup.haha.perflib.** 
-dontwarn com.squareup.haha.trove.** 
-dontwarn com.squareup.leakcanary.** 
-keep class com.squareup.haha.** { *; }

#coroutines
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatcherFactory {}
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandler {}
-keepclassmembernames class kotlinx.** {
    volatile <fields>;
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: THANK YOU..i tried your solution but its not working but ...i found that library given proguard rules........but i do not understand how it works ...  if you have any idea please give me idea about proguard rules

Comment: You have to put it in `proguard-rules.pro` file

Comment: yes ..i put it into proguard-rules.pro file ... its working